# How to run Java .class file from another .class file? (java newb)

Tags: java, file, netbeans, package

I've been running different individual Java .java files in the Netbeans IDE by right-clicking the .java files themselves in the Project Explorer of Netbeans (the portion normally at the upper left part of Netbeans).

However, i've been googling on how to make a class file run another class file using code, but to no avail.

I have a project named "loadanotherfile" with 2 files, namely: Loadanotherfile.java and otherfile.java

I'm trying to make Loadanotherfile.java run otherfile.java, but I'm not exactly sure how. I read about Classloaders and URLClassloaders however these methods don't seem suitable for my purpose of running another .java file.

Below is the code of the 2 files i mentioned.

**Loadanotherfile.java**

```
package loadanotherfile;

public class Loadanotherfile {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

**otherfile.java**

```
package loadanotherfile;

public class otherfile {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("This is the other file.");
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that the task has something to do with using the "import" syntax (namely something like **import loadanotherfile.***  but even if my guess is correct, I'm still not sure on how to make my Loadanotherfile.java run otherfile.java using code.

How can I load otherfile.java using Loadanothefile.java?

Cheers

Comment: The purpose of running other class file is not clear. To load a class in memory you can use `Class.forName("className");` method by specifying the name of the class as a parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Loadanotherfile.java

```
otherfile.main(args);
```

Answer (score 7):

Compile the two together, and then from `Loadanotherfile`,

```
otherfile.main(args);
```

will do the trick. You don't need to import since you're in the same [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html). Note the linked tutorial.

I would investigate (however) class instantiation, and creating an instance of a new class to invoke upon. Invoking static methods from static methods isn't very OO.

Comment: yes, this did the trick, also had to add a line similar to Matt Clark's answer (otherfile otherFile = new otherfile();)

thanks!

Comment: @LastManStanding You would not have to add that extra line. It will work without that.

Comment: @LastManStanding, if you had to do that, then `main()` from `otherfile` is not `static` as you stated.

Comment: @rid Or he is mixing with the casing. He probably tried with `otherFile.main(args);` instead of `otherfile.main(args);`.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
className.main(Args){
}
```

This works! ive tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `public void main` line. If there *IOException* and not there then insert
in *Loadanotherfile.java*

use this

```
otherfile.main(args);{
}
```